# Foreign key doesn't have a default value

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

this is my User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
    private Collection<Address> addresses;
}
```

and this is my Address.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "TOWN")
    private String town;

    @Column(name = "DISTRICT")
    private String district;

    @Column(name = "COUNTRY")
    private String country;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false, nullable=false)
    private User user;    
}
```

but while I'm trying to persist the object I'm getting this exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [com.kpowd.model.Address]
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
root cause

javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [com.kpowd.model.Address]
    javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:101)
    javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:798)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1331)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:181)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:645)
root cause

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [com.kpowd.model.Address]
    org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
    org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1315)
    org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1321)
    org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:843)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.persist(Unknown Source)
    com.kpowd.dao.basedao.GenericDaoImpl.create(GenericDaoImpl.java:47)
    com.kpowd.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.registerUser(UserServiceImpl.java:34)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.registerUser(Unknown Source)
    com.kpowd.controller.UserRegistrationBean.register(UserRegistrationBean.java:80)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:101)
    javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:798)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1331)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:181)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:645)
root cause

org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [com.kpowd.model.Address]
    org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
    org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
    org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:64)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2345)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2852)
    org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71)
    org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
    org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320)
    org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
    org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129)
    org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:69)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:179)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:799)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:791)
    org.hibernate.engine.EJB3CascadingAction$1.cascade(EJB3CascadingAction.java:48)
    org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392)
    org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335)
    org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204)
    org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:425)
    org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:362)
    org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:338)
    org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204)
    org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161)
    org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:475)
    org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:353)
    org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
    org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129)
    org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:69)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:179)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:61)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:808)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:782)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:786)
    org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:837)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.persist(Unknown Source)
    com.kpowd.dao.basedao.GenericDaoImpl.create(GenericDaoImpl.java:47)
    com.kpowd.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.registerUser(UserServiceImpl.java:34)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.registerUser(Unknown Source)
    com.kpowd.controller.UserRegistrationBean.register(UserRegistrationBean.java:80)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:101)
    javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:798)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1331)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:181)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:645)
root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Field 'USER_ID' doesn't have a default value
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3558)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3490)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2109)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2648)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2077)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2362)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2280)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2265)
    org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:94)
    org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:57)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2345)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2852)
    org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71)
    org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
    org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320)
    org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
    org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129)
    org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:69)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:179)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:799)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:791)
    org.hibernate.engine.EJB3CascadingAction$1.cascade(EJB3CascadingAction.java:48)
    org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392)
    org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335)
    org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204)
    org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:425)
    org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:362)
    org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:338)
    org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204)
    org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161)
    org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:475)
    org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:353)
    org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
    org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129)
    org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:69)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:179)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:61)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:808)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:782)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:786)
    org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:837)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.persist(Unknown Source)
    com.kpowd.dao.basedao.GenericDaoImpl.create(GenericDaoImpl.java:47)
    com.kpowd.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.registerUser(UserServiceImpl.java:34)
```

Error wont come if i remove the "NOTNULL" Constraint from the FORIGN_KEY "USER_ID"
but i need to make it as a NOTNULL Column how should i want to do that. please help me??

this is my register methode

```
public String register() {
        // Output some info     


        Address a = new Address();
        a.setCountry("country1");
        a.setDistrict("district1");
        a.setTown("town");

        Address b = new Address();
        b.setCountry("country2");
        b.setDistrict("district2");
        b.setTown("town2");

        List<Address> adrlist=new ArrayList<Address>();
        adrlist.add(a);
        adrlist.add(b);

        User user = new User();
        user.setFirstName("firstname");
        user.setLastName("lastname");
        user.setEmail("email");
        user.setAddresses(adrlist);


        // Call the business object to register the user
        userService.registerUser(user);

        // Set the message here
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Registration success", "success");  
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        System.out.println("befor redirect");
        return "index?faces-redirect=true";
    }
```

and this is my SQL Script

```
CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS `myshop`;
USE `myshop`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user`;
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FIRST_NAME` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LAST_NAME` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EMAIL` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=46 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `address`;
CREATE TABLE `address` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TOWN` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DISTRICT` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COUNTRY` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `USER_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `FK_USER_idx` (`USER_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_USER` FOREIGN KEY (`USER_ID`) REFERENCES `user` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 1):

To me, it looks like you have specified your relationship wrong. Have a look my Q&A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257449/how-do-i-use-annotations-to-define-x-relationship-in-hibernate-4-and-spring). You specifically want to be looking at the uni-directional 1 to many example. With your current configuration I think Hibernate is trying to create 2 uni-directional 1 to many relationships and that is causing issues.

Specifying `insertable = false, updateable = false, nullable = false` on your `@JoinColumn` annotation won't be doing anything. Those modifiers only do something if you are using Hibernate to create your database schema based on your annotations. Since you already have a schema, it doesn't do anything.

It would be helpful for debugging purposes if you could post your `registerUser` method.

```
public class Address implements Serializable {
    ....
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    private User user;
}

public class User implements Serializable{
    ....
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<Address> addresses;
}
```

Comment: FYI it works when i remove the "NOTNULL" constraint form the DB for the foreign key "USER_ID" from the Table "address"

Comment: Yes, it would make it go away, your foreign key isn't getting set by Hibernate, because your relationship is not set up correctly.

Comment: now im getting Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.kpowd.model.Address.USER_ID in com.kpowd.model.User.addresses

Comment: now im getting "mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.kpowd.model.Address.USER_ID in com.kpowd.model.User.addresses"

Comment: Where is my head today? Its been one of those days. see update

Comment: as it seems it s the previouse edit that gives me the same error, any ways i'll try

Comment: now im getting the run time exception com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'USER_ID' cannot be null

Comment: is there no solution for this problem

Comment: are you adding addresses to the `User` then saving the `User`? Because if you aren't then it would cause this issue

Comment: i just did this thing according to this blog http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-many-annotation-tutorial/

Comment: That blog is now 3 years and an entire Hibernate version out of date

Comment: yep, James have u seen my register method? im adding the user like that.

Comment: doesn't look like it too me

Comment: then how did it works when i remove the "NOTNULL" Constraint form DB?

Comment: because your foreign key wasn't being created

Comment: yep i know. but the case is i need that constraint to be as NOTNULL if u found a way let me know?

Answer (score 1):

As the exception you are getting is `java.sql.SQLException: Field 'USER_ID' doesn't have a default value` You can set a default value for your column in Hibernate using annotation like `@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false, nullable=false), columnDefinition = “int default 100"`

You can give any value in spite of 100 what you want to be your default value.

Second thing, may be you would like to add somewhere `referencedColumnName = "SOME_COLUMN"` when you are making foreign keys.

Hope it helps.

Edit:

Please let me explain a bit, the referencedColumnName can be used to specify another column as the default id column of the other table.

```
Table1
    id int identity
    tableb_key varchar


Table2
    id int identity
    key varchar unique

// in class for Table1
@Joincolumn(column="tableb_key", referencedColumnName="key")
```

Comment: i dnt want to set a default value for the column. i cant understand where to put referencedColumnName, can u explain to me how should i put referencedColumnName?

Answer (score -1):

When doing OneToMany and ManyToOne, you have to do add Parent object in you Chilid object as well Child in Parent Ojbect
I mean you need to do 
a.setUser(user);
b.setUser(user);