# Hibernate Many-to-many with extra column do not insert children

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I have an issue with my Hibernate app,
I have model as below:

*Team.java*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEAM")
public class Team implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "antony", strategy = "increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "antony")
@Column(name = "TEAM_ID")
int id;


@Column(name = "TEAM_NAME")
String name;


@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.team")
@Column(name="TEAM_ID")
private Set<TeamMatchReference> teamMatchs = new HashSet<TeamMatchReference>(0);
```

*Match.java*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MATCHS")
public class Match implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "antony", strategy = "increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "antony")
@Column(name = "MATCH_ID")
int id;

//........  

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.match")
@Column(name="MATCH_ID")  
private Set<TeamMatchReference> teamMatchs = new HashSet<TeamMatchReference>(0);
```

*TeamMatchId.java*

```
@Embeddable
public class TeamMatchId implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@ManyToOne
private Team team;

@ManyToOne
private Match match;
```

*TeamMatchReference .java*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "team_match_reference")
@AssociationOverrides({ 
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.team", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TEAM_ID")),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.match", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "MATCH_ID")) })
public class TeamMatchReference implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private TeamMatchId pk;

@Column(name = "BET")
private float bet;

@Column(name = "SCORE")
private Integer score;
```

Then, I try to add new or update an `Match` object. The `match` was updated but its children - `TeamMatchReference` - were not updated, they're not inserted or deleted when I add or remove from the `match.teamMatchReferenceSet`.

Please help to make my code will update - insert and delete - the children when I update and save the `match` object.

Comment: If you are confused about all the different relationships and how to configure them with Hibernate, have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257449/how-do-i-use-annotations-to-define-x-relationship-in-hibernate-4-and-spring). I wrote a Q&A on exactly that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use cascade

```
@OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
```

There are different cascade type. You can select the one that fits your requirement.

Comment: Thank @Pratik, I fixed my code and it worked.

    `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.match", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
 @Column(name = "MATCH_ID")
 private Set<TeamMatchReference> teamMatchs = new HashSet<TeamMatchReference>(0);`