# Spring Hibernate "No Current Transaction" for getCurrentSession method

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am using the Spring configuration to test Spring-Hibernate Transactions.

```
<beans ...>

    <tx:annotation-driven  transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!--  hibernate 4 onwards annotationsessionfactorybean is replaced with localsessionfactory bean -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.fg.arch.test.transaction.Foo</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext</prop> -->
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

My service layer is annotated with `@Transactional`.

This is my DAO:

```
public class FooHibernateDaoImpl implements FooDao {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;  

    public void testFoo(Foo foo) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(" --- ");
        sessionFactory.openSession().save(foo);     
    }
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Explicitly opening the session using the `openSession()` method does not cause a problem however when I change to `getCurrentSession()` I am getting an exception.

I have two questions.

1. Is it good practice to call `openSession()` in every DAO method.
2. How can I make `getCurrentSession()` work so that it will not give me an exception like no active transaction present ?

Thanks.

Comment: Remove `hibernate.current_session_context_class` that breaks proper spring tx management. Never set it when using spring unless you are using JTA. And make sure that your `@Transactional` annotated beans are loaded in the same context as where the `<tx:annotation-driven />` is.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions:

1. No, its not. The `@Transactional` annotation that should be on your service class method calling `testFoo()` is opening the session for you. You should use `getCurrentSession()` in the DAO to get this session.
2. You can, but you shouldn't. That's the entire point of using the Hibernate `SessionFactory` with annotation based transaction management. As long as you are marking your service methods transactional, you shouldn't have a problem.

As a side note, why are you not Autowiring your `SessionFactory`? Don't use setters to set something that should be Autowired. Otherwise you may as well not use Spring.

Comment: Thanks James, but then for getCurrentSession why i am getting exception "save is not valid without active trasaction"

Comment: is the service implementing an interface and is the method calling your `testFoo` method annotated as `@Transactional`

Comment: also as a shameless self-plug if you are new to Hibernate you might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257449/how-do-i-use-annotations-to-define-x-relationship-in-hibernate-4-and-spring) helpful

Comment: Yes. My service is implementing an interface but method is not marked @transactional

Comment: See my update, a session won't be created if your service layer isn't marked `@Transactional` because the Hibernate `TransactionManager` won't be invoked

Comment: I have marked Service class @Transactional so my understanding is all methods will be transactional. right ?

Comment: In theory yes, but theories are treacherous things. Post your entire service class

Comment: Fixed the Issue. It was because of the below mentioned property. <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>