# Hibernate Mapping Exception

Tags: hibernate

I have got two tables orders and orderlines. When i try to join two columns,i am getting this exception.

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: order_id in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(orders) and its related supertables and secondary tables
```

**My entity classes :
Order.java**

```
@Entity  
@Table(name="orders")  
public class Order {  

    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue  
    @Column(name="id")  
    private int id;  

    @Column(name="firstname")  
    private String firstName;  

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=OrderLine.class,  
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,  
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY)  
    @JoinTable(  
            name="orderlines",  
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(table = "orderlines", name="FK_orders_orders",   
            referencedColumnName = "order_id")},  
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(table = "orders", name="FK_orders_orders",   
            referencedColumnName = "id")}  
            )   
    private Set<OrderLine> orderLines;
```

**OrderLine.java**

```
@Entity  
@Table(name="orderlines")  
public class OrderLine {  
     @Id      
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Order.class,  
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,  
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY)  
    @JoinTable(  
            name="orders",  
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(table="orders", name="FK_orders_orders",   
                                        referencedColumnName="id")},  
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(table="orderlines", name="FK_orders_orders",  
                                                referencedColumnName="order_id")})  
    private Order order;  

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Product.class,  
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,  
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY)  
    @JoinTable(  
            name="products",  
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="product_id")  
                )  
    private Product product;
```

My Tables:

**orders**

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (  
`id` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,  
`firstname` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,  
);
```

**orderlines**

```
    CREATE TABLE `orderlines` (
orderLineId int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`orderId` INT NOT NULL,
`product_id` INT NOT NULL,
`quantity` INT NOT NULL,
`product_price` DECIMAL(19,2) NOT NULL,
`total_price` DECIMAL(19,2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(orderLineId),
KEY `FK_orders_orders` (`orderId`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_orders_orders` FOREIGN KEY(`orderId`) REFERENCES `orders`(`id`),
KEY `FK_orders_products`(`product_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_orders_products` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products`(`id`)
);
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: You are creating the relationship incorrectly. Have a look at my tutorial [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257449/how-do-i-use-annotations-to-define-x-relationship-in-hibernate-4-and-spring). That should be able to get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial. I will check now. Can you please point where i am making mistake.

Comment: I'm writing an answer now. You really don't need a join table because you are doing a one-to-many not many-to-many

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be creating your mapping incorrectly. You only need a bi-directional one-to-many with a foreign key mapping. Try this:

```
public class Order{
    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue  
    @Column(name="id")  
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order")
    private Set<OrderLine> orderLines;
}

public class OrderLine{
    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue  
    @Column(name="orderLineId") 
    private int orderLineId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "orderId")
    private Order order;
}
```

You are really overcomplicating your design. You already have a foreign key on the OrderLine table, so why not use that instead of specifying 2 different join tables for this mapping. The above code should work out to be a bi-directional one to many mapping.

Also, as a side note, don't make the PK of OrderLines a composite of Order and Product Id's, just give it its own ID column. It'll make your life a ton easier.

Comment: Could you please help me with table also.

Comment: There shouldn't be anything wrong with your tables, just change the PK on `orderlines` to be a new column that is an auto-incremented int

Comment: i am getting this exception org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert:

Comment: Welcome to Hibernate, you'll need to debug this yourself. It could be thousands of things. Read the exception message carefully, use google, use StackOverflow, you can solve this problem

Comment: Just one thing, i have updated the orderlines table. Just confirm its right or wrong.

Comment: I thought something is wrong with constraints , which is preventing to insert(cause of the exception); That is why asked.

Comment: I think its either your cascade direction, or the order in which you are inserting your objects

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44929/java-spring-struts-hibernate-php-jquery-javascript-beginners

Comment: keep debugging, I think its because your foreign key isn't getting set. Save the Order before you save the OrderLine, or cascade the save operation

Comment: You need to do it yourself. Otherwise how will you solve the next one?

Comment: To get good at Hibernate, read the documentation, then experiment.

Comment: @JamesSolved it finally after a long struggle.