# hibernate lazy error but I don't want those data

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-initialization

I have POJO with couple of strings/numbers/... and I want to get only this pojo, without any sub-POJOs in lists/maps/sets that could be attached by hibernate. If I execute query to get first pojo, exception is thrown when someone touches those subobjects.

This is normal behaviour and I agree with this, but is there a way, not to call this:

```
object.setSomeMap(null);
```

but to set it for default behaviour? I don't see setting each property like this as best solution as I have quite big model for everything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set your `FetchType` to `FetchType.LAZY` and they won't be loaded when you load your class from the database. I'll give you an example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FOO")
public class Foo{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String prop1;

    @Column
    private String prop2;

    //You don't have to set fetch type like this, as lazy is the default for collections,
    //but it doesn't really hurt anything
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Bar> listOfBars;
}
```

So when you load up your `Foo` class, `id`, `prop1` and `prop2` will be loaded and set from the database, but the `listOfBars` objects will not be populated.

Whenever you try to access the `listOfBars` objects, Hibernate detects it and tries to populate the objects before you can get it. AFAIK if you try and set `listOfBars` to null, Hibernate will detect this and try to delete your foreign keys, effectively removing all the members of `listOfBars` if you update the object. Eg:

```
@Transactional
public Foo doStuffWithFoo(int id){
    Foo foo = fooDao.find(id);
    //Set listOfBars to null so we can't call it.
    //This is bad and will cause disaster when we update Foo.
    foo.setListOfBars(null);

    //Do some stuff with Foo that changes values.

    fooDao.saveOrUpdate(foo);
    return foo;
}
```

Because you set your `listOfBars` object to null here, AFAIK Hibernate will then delete all your foreign keys because your list doesn't exist any more. Hibernate knows the difference between a list that is empty because it didn't populate it when it created the object and a list that you have set to null/emptied. If the case of the former, it doesn't do anything except perhaps cascade the updated status if it needs to. In the case of the latter, it will clear your associations, possibly deleting Bar objects, if you have `orphanRemoval` set to true.

However if you do try to access your `listOfBars` once you have returned `Foo` out of the method you get another problem. This problem occurs because the `@Transactional` session you originally used to fetch your `Foo` class has ended before you try to access your `listOfBars`. You have 3 options at this point, each with their own problems.

The first option (which is what most people try, and get frustrated because it doesn't work) is you can open a new session, and try to populate your `listOfBars` object. Hibernate assumes that both your `Foo` object and all the `Bar` objects in your `listOfBars` could have changed since the transaction was ended (which is perfectly true), so it throws an exception.

Another option is to fetch the entire `Foo` object *again* and populate the `listOfBars` object in your new transaction. The problem with this is that its quite inefficient to be doing multiple selects like this.

Your final option is to never try and access your `listOfBars` object if you know that its not there. You can't even perform a null check because Hibernate will detect your call to `getListOfBars()` and try and populate the object before the null check actually happens.

I have written a Hibernate tutorial for creating object relationships [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257449/how-do-i-use-annotations-to-define-x-relationship-in-hibernate-4-and-spring) that you might find helpful. I also discuss things like Lazy vs Eager object fetching for collections as well as a few other Hibernate things that can be helpful when designing classes for use with Hibernate.

Best of luck

Comment: Hey James. Thanks for this answer but I'm already familiar with all this but problem is that when I try to marshal this object via jackosn or xstream it throws lazy loading error, of course because there is no more session when it gets there. That's why I have to set null value so I overwrite PersisteceSet or PersistenceList that has listeners on it. I want to send only main object, without objects that could be attached to it. I hope that clears it. But your answer is good so leave it for some others if they face something familiar.

Comment: ahhhh, you want the `@JsonIgnore` annotation. Annotate your collection with that annotation and Jackson won't try and serialize it to JSON. This is a classic [X-Y Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: "effectively removing all the members of listOfBars" - I don't think this is the case. It just removes relation but rows in database stays. You must call .clear() on list to remove them from database as well.

Comment: If you have `orphanRemoval=true` and you remove the last relation to that object, Hibernate will delete the row.

Comment: Yes I could do that, but if I want to use it in another method, I will not get it so annotation is not a solution for me neither. It's tricky case I agree...

Comment: I suppose, you could totally detach the object, set the collection to null, and then serialize it with Jackson. That way Hibernate won't know that you've updated the collection

Comment: Hehe, I'm doing this already but is there any way to tell hibernate not to initialize lists if session is not opened? Like setting this default behaviour to, let's say, ignore this error?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware, Hibernate was designed to populate objects in this manner.

Comment: Ok then. Thank you for your help :) Please add this line to your answer so I can accept it.