# how to properly set up hibernate unidirectional one-to-one mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, one-to-one

i have two tables which has `one-to-one` mapping on a column. i'd like to set up `unidirectional one-to-one` hibernate mapping using annotations because i want to be able to get results from joined tables, but do not want to do foreign constraint check for child table.

here's my quick code.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class student {

// primary key and other column definition here..

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="address_id")
    private Address address;

// getters and //setters
}

@Entity
@Tale(name = "address") 
public class address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "hibernate-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "hibernate-uuid", strategy = uuid")
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, length = 36, nullable = false)
    private String id;

    @Column(name="address_id")
    private String address_id;

    // getters and setters
}
```

above gives me following exception when i try to insert into student (but not the address).

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering com.test.Student from com.test.Address has the wrong number of column. should be 2
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: If you are new to Hibernate you might find my tutorial [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257449/how-do-i-use-annotations-to-define-x-relationship-in-hibernate-4-and-spring) to be of some use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, change cascade type to REFRESH in `student` class (better to remove it). Then if it is unidirectional, means the other part won't know anything of it. So you should add `referenceColumnName` to your @OneToOne

`@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` 
`@JoinColumn(name = "PK_OF_THE_OTHER_TABLE", referencedColumnName = "CURRENT_TABLE_COLUMN_REFERENCE",` `nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)`

By this implementation, you will not update the other part but joining and get information you need

**UPDATE --** `PK_OF_THE_OTHER_TABLE` is the primary key of `address` table. Also `CURRENT_TABLE_COLUMN_REFERENCE` is your Foreign Key (current table's field which is pointing to `address` table) - I assumed you put your one to one relationship in `Student` entity.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. i updated my code with your suggestion except i excluded nullable=false part. but i get exception because returning result set from join table asks for PK_OF_THE_OTHER_TABLE from student table which doesn't exist.

Comment: i eventually googled and found out that name and referenceColumnName value was swapped in your first posting. but nevertheless i took your approach and so far it seems to work. only issue i'm facing now is that when i try to fetch a record from joint table when there's no records to join, hibernate complains about unknown column from child table. but that's a different issue. thanks.

Comment: not a problem. By the way, referencedColumnName is described here:
http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/JoinColumn/referencedColumnName