# hibernate one to many annotation confusion

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm not understanding how to do something that is probably very easy to do.  I have a table named "Composer".  A "Composer" can have many compositions ("Composition" table).  I get the following error when I run this through Spring Boot:

```
19:11:40 web.1  | Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: 
mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: 
com.zack.music.domain.Composition.composition in com.zack.music.domain.Composer.compositions
```

Below are my entity classes.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
package com.zack.music.domain;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.*;

@Entity
public class Composer implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String name;

    private Date birth;
    private Date death;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="composition")
    private List<Composition> compositions;

    protected Composer() { }

    public Composer(String name, Date birth, Date death) {
        this.name = name;
        this.birth = birth;
        this.death = death;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getBirth() {
        return birth;
    }

    public void setBirth(Date birth) {
        this.birth = birth;
    }

    public Date getDeath() {
        return death;
    }

    public void setDeath(Date death) {
        this.death = death;
    }

    public List<Composition> getCompositions() {
        return compositions;
    }

    public void setCompositions(List<Composition> compositions) {
        this.compositions = compositions;
    }
}

@Entity
public class Composition implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne  
    private Composer composer;

    protected Composition() { }

    public Composition(String name, Composer composer) {
        this.name = name;
        this.composer = composer;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Composer getComposer() {
        return composer;
    }

    public void setComposer(Composer composer) {
        this.composer = composer;
    }
}
```

Comment: From your comments on your answer below you seem to be struggling with lazily loaded collections that Jackson is trying to serialize into JSON. Have a look at this basic Hibernate tutorial that I wrote [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24257449/2357233)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it using `@ElementCollection`.  [Java Persistence/ElementCollection](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection) helped me figure it out.  I also filled in the "name" attributes on all of my tables and columns which I think helped identify everything.  Here are the updated entities that are working:

```
package com.zack.music.domain;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.*;

@Entity(name="COMPOSER")
public class Composer implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name="BIRTH", nullable = false)
    private Date birth;

    @Column(name="DEATH", nullable = true)
    private Date death;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(
            name="COMPOSITION",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="COMPOSER", referencedColumnName="NAME")
    )
    @Column(name="NAME")
    private List<String> compositions;

    protected Composer() { }

    public Composer(String name, Date birth, Date death) {
        this.name = name;
        this.birth = birth;
        this.death = death;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getBirth() {
        return birth;
    }

    public void setBirth(Date birth) {
        this.birth = birth;
    }

    public Date getDeath() {
        return death;
    }

    public void setDeath(Date death) {
        this.death = death;
    }

    public List<String> getCompositions() {
        return compositions;
    }
}

@Entity(name="COMPOSITION")
public class Composition implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name="COMPOSER", nullable = false)
    private String composer;

    protected Composition() { }

    public Composition(String name, String composer) {
        this.name = name;
        this.composer = composer;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getComposer() {
        return composer;
    }

    public void setComposer(String composer) {
        this.composer = composer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mappedBy` is telling hibernate the property name on the related entity that owns the relationship.  There is no property named 'composition' on the related entity: `Composition`.  You probably just meant for the value of `mappedBy` to be `"composer"`.

Comment: That helped me get it running but now I get this error when I attempt to access Composer through my RestController:

Comment: 19:27:35 web.1  | 2014-10-22 19:27:35.283 ERROR 51088 --- [ qtp32696411-21] o.h.
engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unknown column 'compositio0_.composer_nam
e' in 'field list'

Comment: Not to my knowledge.  I'm rebuilding this with 'mvn clean package' and executing it locally with heroku foreman

Comment: This is what comes back from my RestController...Wed Oct 22 19:32:48 EDT 2014

There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).

Could not write JSON: could not extract ResultSet (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.zack.music.domain.Composer["compositions"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not extract ResultSet (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.zack.music.domain.Composer["compositions"])