# Hibernate - Does hibernate use proxy objects if there is no associations?

Tags: java, hibernate, proxy

There is no association in the entity shown below.
Does hibernate use proxy object to retrieve the User object?
The question is little bit same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26622719/hibernate-does-hibernate-always-use-object-proxies).
But what if there is no associations?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just test?

Comment: I couldn't find a way to test it.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to test for proxy

```
boolean proxy = user instanceof HibernateProxy;
```