# Hibernate persist Map<String, String> without referencing another tables

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

*Could you please help me to persist map of strings with Hibernate?*

Map values come from client and are random, so I don't want to store separate table for map's values

### Exception

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Associated class not
>   found: java.lang.String

### Code

```
@Entity
public class UserConfig {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "CONFIG_SEQ", name = "ConfigSeq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ConfigSeq")
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class)
    @CollectionTable(name = "MAP")
    @MapKey(name="key")
    @Column(name="value")
    private Map<String, String> map;
```

### Update

*Could you please also explain how to persist `Map<MyEnum, String>` , if `MyEnum` is an unmapped class?*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the specification, you should annotate the map like this:

```
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class)
    @CollectionTable(name = "MAP")
    @MapKeyColumn(name="key")
    @Column(name="value")
    private Map<String, String> map;
```

So `@MapKeyColumn`, instead of `@MapKey`.

This is the way you should annotate the map when its defined as:

```
private Map<Basic, Basic> map; // (i.e. Map<String, String>)
```

You use the `@MapKey` annotation when you have map defined as:

```
private Map<Basic, Entity> map; // (i.e. Map<String, User>)
```

And finally, you use `@MapKeyEnumerated` annotation when you have map defined ad:

```
private Map<Enumeration, Basic> map; // (i.e. Map<MyEnum, String>)
```

Comment: additionally, `targetClass` can also be omitted if we are using generics

Comment: @MaciejKowalski thanks for your answer! Could you plsease also explain how to make `Map<MyEnum, String> `, if `MyEnum` is unmapped class?

Comment: Based on my notes while i was preparing for the JPA Certificate that is possible. Please find the answer in the edited post.

Comment: Anyone know if I can do this in XML mappings with Hibernate?

Comment: may I use Map<String, Object>?