# AnnotationException Referenced property not a (One|Many)ToOne

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I tried to make one-to-one relationship. But I get error:

```
AnnotationException Referenced property not a (One|Many)ToOne
on
com.student.information.service.Department.departmentId in mappedBy of com.student.information.service.DepartmentHead.department
```

Both the entities are almost identical. Department can exists with out department head.

Department.Java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="department", catalog="student")
public class Department {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer departmentId;

    @Column(name="dept_name")
    private String departmentName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="department",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Student> student; 

    @OneToOne(targetEntity=Department.class)
    private DepartmentHead departmenthead;
}
```

DepartmentHead.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="departmenthead", catalog = "student")
public class DepartmentHead {

    //This is mapped with the department id

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="headname")
    private String headName;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "departmentId",fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="dept_id")
    private Department department;  
}
```

Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Referenced property not a (One|Many)ToOne:

can someone please point me in the right direction about what mistake am I making. I am struggling from past 2 days and not able to figure out the solution for the issue. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: You may find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24257450/2357233)  I wrote to be helpful. It will show you how to set up a bi-directional one to one relationship.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have incorrectly set up your mapping. Hibernate is complaining that no field called `departmentId` is available to set up a one to one or many relationship, and it is correct.

You want to map your values like this.

Department.Java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="department", catalog="student")
public class Department {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer departmentId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private DepartmentHead departmenthead;
}
```

DepartmentHead.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="departmenthead", catalog = "student")
public class DepartmentHead {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "departmenthead")
    private Department department;  
}
```

You point the `Department` field in `DepartmentHead` at the `DepartmentHead` field inside the `Department`. Hibernate sorts out what ID's to use, you don't have to specify that in the actual link.

Comment: thanks for your help. It worked like a charm. Accepting it as an answer, thanks once again, you saved my lot of hours

Answer (score 0):

How about the Student class. Have you defined ManyToOne relationship in the Student class.

```
    @Entity
    public class Student {
      @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private int id;
      private String name;

      @ManyToOne
     private Department department;
     ..................
```

Please check [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0355__JPA/OneToManyWithOrderBySetting.htm).