# Problems with identifiing entity in another entity using Hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Here is **the code:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class BotUser {

    ...

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
    private int id;    

    @OneToOne
    private Equipment equipment;

    ...

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Equipment {

    ...

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    ...

}
```

When Hibernate is fetching equipment data from PostrgeSQL table, he requests "equipment_id" field, not "id". How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must use @JoinColumn annotation. And to be sure I added CascadeType.ALL

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class BotUser {

    ...   

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Equipment equipment;

    ...

}
```

The same problem: [AnnotationException Referenced property not a (One|Many)ToOne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28710346/annotationexception-referenced-property-not-a-onemanytoone/28710576)