# Hibernate deleted object would be re-saved by cascade

Tags: hibernate, exception, one-to-many, removechild

I'm trying to delete a child entity in hibernate but get this exception:

```
 org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [com.epic.ecommerce.core.model.Customer#newnameTest]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.forceFlush(SessionImpl.java:1236)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:187)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:114)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:684)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:676)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$5.cascade(CascadingActions.java:235)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293)...
```

these are my entities:

```
@Entity
```

@Table(name="CUSTOMER")
public class Customer {

```
    @Id
    @Column(name="customer_id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
    @GenericGenerator(name="gen", strategy="foreign",parameters=@Parameter(name="property", value="user"))
    private String id;
```

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="customerId",orphanRemoval=true)
    private Set quoteConfigs;

```
    public Set<QuoteConfiguration> getQuoteConfigs() {
    return quoteConfigs;
    }

    public void setQuoteConfigs(Set<QuoteConfiguration> quoteConfigs) {
    this.quoteConfigs = quoteConfigs;
    }


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private User user;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }



@Entity
@Table(name="quote_configuration")
public class QuoteConfiguration implements java.io.Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "quote_id",unique = true, nullable = false)  
private Integer quoteId;

@Column(name = "base_product", nullable = false)
private String baseProduct;

@Column(name = "quote_name")
private String quoteName;   

/*
@Column(name = "customer_customer_id")
private String customerId;

public String getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
}

public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
}
*/
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL) 
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_customer_id")
private Customer customerId;


public Customer getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
}

public void setCustomerId(Customer customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
}
```

This the part when I'm trying to remove

```
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query q = session.createQuery("from QuoteConfiguration where quoteId = :quoteId ");
    q.setParameter("quoteId", quoteId);
    QuoteConfiguration quote = (QuoteConfiguration)q.list().get(0);

    Query qc=session.createQuery("from Customer where id=:id");
    qc.setParameter("id", quote.getCustomerId().getId());

    Customer customer=(Customer)qc.list().get(0);
    customer.getQuoteConfigs().remove(quote);
    session.delete(quote);
    session.save(customer);
```

My question is how can I remove the child entity QuoteConfiguration, without getting that association exception in Customer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `session.delete(quote)` from your code.

Your `@OneToMany` Collection is the **master** of your records, and it is already set to **remove orphans** elements. So, when you do `customer.getQuoteConfigs().remove(quote)`, it already tells Hibernate to delete the record from database.

---

On a side note, you should try `session.get(class, id)` instead of using HQL to fetch single instances.

You don't need to `save(customer)` since Hibernate always keeps track of persisted instances. They will be saved automatically when the transaction is closed (unless your session is set to Manual, which it shouldn't be).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Guillaume F. , but is still giving me the same exception, do you know any other way that I could remove this child?

Comment: Make sure that all your @OneToMany and @ManyToOne relations are set to `(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)`loading. Also, verify that you don't have other Collections loaded in your Session.

Comment: Take a look at this post, it's interesting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257449/how-do-i-use-annotations-to-define-different-types-of-relationships-in-hibernate/24257450#24257450

Comment: I did another fix, changed the fetchType in both entities and change the removal in my DAO