# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails using Hibernate Framework

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Is there anybody can help me to solve this problem?

I am trying to save student's record one at a time in my system and save it to different tables in my database but i got error when saving it.

It involves 4 Classes namely **Personalinfo.java**(Parent Class) ,
 **Student.java**(Child Class-extends Personalinfo.java), **Students_Credentials.java**(Links to Student.java) and **ManageStudent.class**(contains method that saves the student's record)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fT2xW.png)

[Database Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2SPF.png)

Heres the Code:

> PersonalInfo.java

```
//PersonalInfo.java

@Entity
@Table(name="personal_info")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)  
public class Personalinfo {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name="personalid")
  private long personalUID;
  @Column(name="lastname")
  private String lastname;
  @Column(name="firstname")
  private String firstname;
  @Column(name="middlename")
  private String middlename;
  @Column(name="Suffix")
  private String suffix;
  @Column(name="gender")
  private String gender;
  @Column(name="homeaddress")
  private String homeaddress;
  @Column(name="birthdate")
  private String birthdate;
  @Column(name="bloodtype")
  private String bloodtype;
  @Column(name="contactno")
  private String contactno;
  @Column(name="email")
  private String email;
  @Column(name="cplastname")
  private String cplastname;
  @Column(name="cpfirstname")
  private String cpfirstname;
  @Column(name="cpmiddlename")
  private String cpmiddlename;
  @Column(name="cphomeaddress")
  private String cphomeaddress;
  @Column(name="cpcontactno")
  private String cpcontactno;
  @Column(name="photo")
  private Blob photo;
  @Column(name="note")
  private String note;

  //(Netbeans)Automated Get & Set Method..

}
```

> Student.java

```
//Student.java

@Entity
@Table(name="student")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="personalid") 

public class Student extends Personalinfo {

    @Column(name="studentidno",unique=true,nullable=false)
    private String stud_id;

    @Column(name="gradeschool")
    private String grade_school;

    @Column(name="gs_aygraduated")
    private String gs_ay_graduated;

    @Column(name="highschool")
    private String high_school;

    @Column(name="hs_aygraduated")
    private String hs_ay_graduated;

    @Column(name="college")
    private String College;

    @Column(name="c_aygraduated")
    private String c_ay_graduated;

    //(Netbeans)Automated Get & Set Method..

}
```

> Students_Credentials.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="students_credentials")

public class Students_Credentials {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="studentscredentialsid",unique=true,nullable=false)
    private long stud_credentials_id;

    @Column(name="credentialsnamesubmitted")
    private String credentials_name_submitted;


    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="studentidno")
    private Student Student;

   //(Netbeans)Automated Get & Set Method..

}
```

> ManageStudent.java

```
public static void addStudent(String Lastname,String Firstname,String Middlename,String Suffix,String ContactNo.......)
  {
    Session session = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try
    {
        //***personal_info table(Parent Class) and student table(Student Class extends Personal_info Class) ***

        tx = session.beginTransaction();   
        Student stud=new Student();
        stud.setLastname(Lastname);
        stud.setFirstname(Firstname);
        stud.setMiddlename(Middlename);
        stud.setSuffix(Suffix);
        stud.setGender(Gender);
        stud.setGender(Gender);
        stud.setHomeaddress(HomeAddress);
        stud.setBirthdate(Birthdate);
        stud.setContactno(ContactNo);
        stud.setEmail(Email);
        stud.setCplastname(CPLastname);
        stud.setCpfirstname(CPFirstname);
        stud.setCpmiddlename(CPMiddlename);
        stud.setCphomeaddress(CPHomeAddress);
        stud.setCpcontactno(CPContactNo);
        stud.setPhoto(Photo);
        stud.setNote(Note);
        stud.setStud_id(IDno);
        stud.setGrade_school(GradeSchool);
        stud.setGs_ay_graduated(GSAYGraduated);
        stud.setHigh_school(HighSchool);
        stud.setHs_ay_graduated(HSAYGraduated);
        stud.setCollege(College);
        stud.setC_ay_graduated(CollAYGraduated);


        //***students_credentials table(Students_Credentials class)***

        Students_Credentials Stud_Cred0=new Students_Credentials("Form 138");
        Students_Credentials Stud_Cred1=new Students_Credentials("NSO");
        Students_Credentials Stud_Cred2=new Students_Credentials("HD");

        Stud_Cred0.setStudent(stud);
        Stud_Cred1.setStudent(stud);
        Stud_Cred2.setStudent(stud);

        session.persist(stud);

        session.persist(Stud_Cred0);
        session.persist(Stud_Cred1);
        session.persist(Stud_Cred2);


        tx.commit();
    }
    catch (HibernateException e)
    {
      if (tx != null) {
        tx.rollback();
      }
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
      session.close();
    }
  }
```

Comment: You don't have an ID on your student object, because it's not been saved. Generated values only get generated on save. I'd double check that your object relations are set up correctly ([see my guide here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24257450/2357233)). If they are, try save your student object first, then try save your student credentials object.

Comment: Hi @JamesENL, i did not put ID on Student object because if i do, the error will occur on Netbeans IDE and says it will create multiple ID's in the entity hierarchy which i think it conflicts the personalinfo_id that student class extends with. I got your point, save the student object first but do you mean create another session transaction to save student credentials object?

Comment: Hi @DawoodibnKareem, yes but i could not figure out what is the problem which i think my SQL Statements and its relations were set-up correctly. I am wondering if it is on the Hibernate Code that bothers me..

Comment: I think you need to add the `@Id` annotation on `private String stud_id;` in the `Student` class.  Can you try that and see?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem , i already tried it and error will occur on Netbeans IDE and says it will create multiple ID's in the entity hierarchy which i think it conflicts the personalinfo_id that student class extends with.

Comment: Then you probably need to remove the `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` annotation.  I don't think you're using it right.

Comment: it must be there because it relies on the personalinfo class to get the foreign key of it ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got too long for a comment and I want to format some code. This is not a full answer, this is me speculating on how this issue might be resolved.

Your error is being caused, because Hibernate is trying to save the StudentCredentials object, without having an id on the Student object it is attached too. Either the ID doesn't exist, or it doesn't match the ID on the student object for some reason.

I've never managed Hibernate transactions and sessions myself. I've always used Hibernate within Spring, which managed the transaction for me.

If I had to guess (and I stress, this is a complete guess) I'd say you have to do the following.

```
create Student
save student
commit **this should put a generated id on the student record**
set Student on Student_Credentials objects
save Student Credentials objects
```

Just as a note, if you are using Hibernate stand alone, then that's your decision, but if you have the option to integration Hibernate with something like Spring, to manage all the minutiae and boilerplate for you, you'll usually make your life easier.

Comment: Yah... Seems like the previous method(addStudent(StudID,Lastname,Credentials..)) does not save all the student's record in just one method due to the id issues i guess. What i did was, i just created another method for saving the Student's Credentials(AddStudentCredentials(StudID,Credentials)). This is another option to save.Thank You.