# Hibernate odd behavior with @OneToMany and updating

Tags: mysql, hibernate, kotlin

Let me give you the simplified situation.

**Article class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="article")
data class Article (

    @Id
    var id: String = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString(),

    @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    var keywords: MutableList<Keyword> = mutableListOf()
)
```

**Keyword class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="keyword")
data class Keyword(

    @Id
    var id: String = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString(),

    var keyword: String = ""
)
```

This situation *automatically* generated an extra table named "article_keyword" that is essentially a join table between `Article` and `Keyword`. This is all makes sense and works just fine.

**The problem**

Let's say `Article` has 10 `Keyword` objects in it's list, this is persisted. This `Article` is fetched again and one `Keyword` is removed and the object is saved it tells me this:

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

It says it specifically on the *generated* `article_keyword` table concerning `Article_id` in that table. It tries to update the `article_keyword` join table but can't delete any relation as it has a foreign key constraint to the `Article` object itself. It makes sense. Yet, I don't know how to solve it.

I've tried numerous things, like adding the `@JoinTable` specification that Hibernate has generated. Adding `orphanRemoval` and many other things. Without result.

*note: I've tried the queries that Hibernate executes in mysql myself, they work fine, that might be a hint??*

---

**Update: The saga continues**
As it happens with posting your issue on Stackoverflow, I've resolved it to a certain extent.

In order to work around it for now, as I had to have it working right now, I turned off `foreign_key_checks` just for one operation. After turning it on again to debug some more, no more issues. I made absolutely sure that `foreign_key_checks` are on again and they are.

The one thing that has changed is that no longer there is a `foreign_key` on the column `Article_id` of the table `article_keyword`. Is this just some Hibernate magic or am I missing something?

I've been trying this for the entire day thus far. The issue has been resolved, but I would still like to understand this behaviour.

Comment: Well based on your update, I'd say you're no longer getting a foreign key constraint because the join table no longer has article_id marked as a foreign key. This probably isn't desirable behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, I can see two potential solutions going forward. You could make the current relationship a bi-directional link, or you could start explicitly managing the join table. I've not worked in Kotlin before, so I'm translating this from a Java context, so you might need to translate my examples back.

**Bi-Directional One to Many Relationship**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="article")
data class Article (

    @Id
    var articleId: String = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString(),

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="keyword")
    var keywords: MutableList<Keyword> = mutableListOf()
)
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name="keyword")
data class Keyword(

    @Id
    var keywordId: String = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString(),

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="articleId")
    var article: Article

    var keyword: String = ""
)
```

OR

**Uni-directional with explicit join table management**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="article")
data class Article (

    @Id
    var articleId: String = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString(),

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name="article_keyword,
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="articleId"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="keywordId"))
    var keywords: MutableList<Keyword> = mutableListOf()
)
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name="keyword")
data class Keyword(

    @Id
    var keywordId: String = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString(),

    var keyword: String = ""
)
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name="article_keyword")
data class articlekeyword(

    var articleKeywordId: String = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString(),

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="articleId")
    var article: Article

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="keywordId")
    var keyword: Keyword
)
```

My only worry might be that if you choose to do a bi-directional link it may have unintended consequences when you delete things, but that's probably something to test out. I adapted these examples from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24257450/2357233) which you may find useful.